# Jquery stop scroll function after cookie is set

Tags: jquery, html

i have a basic function in jQuery, which shows the element (#test) after scroll and hides it after a `cookie` is set when label (hide this element) is clicked. Issue is when label is clicked the element should stay hidden but now it executes the scroll function again. How could i prevent the scroll function to start if a cookie is set upon clicking the label? I wish to hide it strictly until the cookie expires.

Demo fiddle with current setup: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ob6ymf1p/)

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I got the full intent of the question, but it sounds like the issue is that if you click "hide this element" it still pops up after you start scrolling again.  After you run the page again, it's fine; however, if you don't reload it, then it keeps showing the popup on scroll.  You can prevent that from happening by removing the event listener for the scroll event.  It's best to specify which listener function you want to remove so other functions that rely on listening to the scroll event don't break.  First step is to give your event function a handle (so we can reference it later):

```
var funcdec;
$(window).on('scroll', funcdec = function() {
    ...
```

Then, after the user clicks the label you can remove that listener:

```
$('.close').on('click', function(){
    hideElement();
    $(window).off('scroll', funcdec);
});
```

Here's a fork of your demo: https://jsfiddle.net/qn7kdwxu/
And here is a fork of your demo that doesn't test for the cookie so you can see it in action: https://jsfiddle.net/qn7kdwxu/1/

Comment: Spot on, wasn't sure about how to remove the event listener after a cookie is set. Works like a charm, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

if you add this code:

```
if(cookie && cookie[1]==='true') {
   $("#test").hide();
}
```

in the onscroll function, it will check for the cookie to perform the action

Comment: How can i add double if statements? I've tried but no luck.